# what is algorithm for find path planner

Tags: ros, path, planner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I mean global path and local path. as i know Amcl for robot localized known map and i use move base 4 files are base local planner, costmap common, global costmap, local costmap

Please explain me

Thank

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/183165/what-is-algorithm-for-find-path-planner/) by [gdist](https://answers.ros.org/users/15441/gdist/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-07-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have a look at [move_base](http://wiki.ros.org/move_base) documentation and tutorials they will answer your questions.

---

Originally posted by [martimorta](https://answers.ros.org/users/69/martimorta/) with karma: 843 on 2014-07-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1